# TWebBrowser не дает редактировать имена файлов

Tags: файлы, radstudio, c++

Вот такой вот код

```
   WebBrowser1->Navigate(drivePath);
```

где `drivePath` указывает на какую то папку, например `c:\\`
всё отлично работает (как в проводнике) пока дело не доходит до переименования файла или папки, жму переименовать, имя файла выделяется, и всё тут тупик... никакой реакции на любые нажатия клавиш клавиатуры, имя можно например вставить с помощью меню мыши, и всё переименует, но вот с клавиатуры никак не получается... подскажите в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Указывайте хоть, что используете RAD Studio, здесь не медиумы сидят =)

Comment: @Free_ze многие из тех, кто пользуется этим продуктом, не знают, что такие вещи, как **TWebBrowser** отношения к собственно C++ не имеют

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот компонент должен уметь переименовывать? В документации пишут, что: "TWebBrowser is a visual component, that permits loading and displaying the Web content or local files....TWebBrowser offers support for the basic functions of a browser, such as: navigate to URL, go back, go forward, along with specific events."

Comment: @DreamChild 
Данный вопрос из разряда: "Научите меня читать хэлп моей тулзы"

Comment: Понятно, что TWebBrowser к самому языку С++ не имеет отношения. Это был первый вопрос, форма была заполнена по аналогии с другими вопросами по этой теме. Документация была прочитана, и не возникло бы вопроса, если бы например был не активен пункт меню "Переименовать" или бы в принципе нельзя было переименовать. Удалось переименовать папку, файл, но без участия клавиатуры.